# Can the XCode4 version editor use the git log --follow argument?

Tags: git, xcode4

If I rename a source-controlled file in XCode4 (integrated with Git), and then go to the XCode4 version editor (comparison view) and browse the revisions, I notice that the entire revision history is no longer being reported after the renaming of the source file.

Outside of XCode4, if I use "git log --follow SourceFile.m", I can then see the entire history.

Is there a way to set a preference in XCode4 to use the --follow command to report the entire history?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Use git from the command line - at least when you want more power.